Application that allows simulating multiple beaglebones virtually
I managed to create a project using beaglebone to be able to receive and send messages from it and now I am thinking of expanding on it. However, it would involve getting another beaglebone to be able to test it in my expanded project.
So I was wondering if there is a way maybe that I could test my project virtually where I just add an exe file and let it simulate virtually instead of buying another beaglebone?
I have heard of Docker, but I am struggling to be able to be able to use an image as a base of Docker image. I also think that maybe Docker might not be the best application to do the virtual simulation of my project.
BeagleBone Image
